# Atheros AR9285 not working with Linksys RE1000

Tags: windows-7

I have a Linksys E3200 extended with a Linksys RE1000 repeater to which an ASUS EEE PC with Atheros AR9285 is trying to connect to. If I connect the ASUS to the E3200 everything works fine. However if it connects to the RE1000 repeater it simply refuses to get a Gateway address. Status is Connected, signal is fine, but Unidentified network. No DHCP-assigned IP address.

I Googled a bit and found a lot of complains about AR9285. I have updated the driver to the latest one I can find on atheros.cz, but still no luck. The ASUS runs Windows 7. We have another Dell that runs Windows 7, but using Intel Wi-Fi adapter and it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a windows update and the problem was fixed.